# Loading native python libraries

Tags: python, module, python-module

Python 2.7 comes with json library included. In my PYTHONPATH I include third party sources and one of them is also called json. The result ending up with loaded the wrong json library. What would be a good practice to handle and avoid situations like above? Is there a way to instruct Python to explicitly load the native library in this fashion `from ? import json`.

Comment: I suggest you try and modify your code and leave Python the way it is. You will have to modify every new module you include to account for your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
from path import json as anotherjson
```

This way the namespace conflict can be removed.

Also you can see the discussions about relative/absolute import.

- http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328

It says :

> In Python 2.5, you can switch import‘s behaviour to absolute imports
>   using a from **future** import absolute_import directive. This
>   absolute- import behaviour will become the default in a future version
>   (probably Python 2.7). Once absolute imports are the default, import
>   string will always find the standard library’s version. It’s suggested
>   that users should begin using absolute imports as much as possible.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
# from standard path
import json as _json 
# from a package
from pkg import json as pkgjson
```

The other technique is to use the [imp](http://effbot.org/librarybook/imp.htm) module

```
import imp
json = imp.load_source('json', '/path/to/json.py')
```

Answer (score 2):

There really is no good way to have multiple modules with the same name on PYTHONPATH[<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path), this means that you should probably move the third party json module to an alternate location that is not on PYTHONPATH, and then import it using some other method.

The easiest way to do this is to move the third party json module into a subdirectory of the location it is already in, and then make that subdirectory a module by adding  __init__.py to it.

If you named this new directory 'thirdparty', you could then import your third party json module using `from thirdparty import json`, and `import json` would always import Python's json module.

Alternatively, you could rename the module to something that does not conflict.